# Laravel create json array from results

Tags: php, laravel

in my application i need to have this format:

```
[
    {"mobileNumber":"00000"},
    {
        "mobileNumber":"AAAA",
        "ewallets": ["11111","2222","3333"]
    },
    {
        "mobileNumber":"BBBB",
        "ewallets": ["11111","2222","3333","4444","5555"]
    }
]
```

now i want to create this format by below code:

```
$contacts = [];
for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($all_data); $idx++) {
    $obj = (Array)$all_data[$idx];
    $mobileNumber = str_replace('-', '', $mobileNumber);

    if($mobileNumber[0] != '0')
        $mobileNumber = '0'.$mobileNumber;
    $data = ContactLists::whereContactMobileNumber($mobileNumber)->exists();
    if($data){

        $contact_ewallets = UserWallets::where('account_number', 'LIKE', '%' . substr($mobileNumber, 1, strlen($mobileNumber)))->get();

        $temp[]['mobileNumber']=$obj["mobileNumber"];

        foreach ($contact_ewallets as $value){
            $ewallet['ewallet'][]=$value->account_number;
        }

        $contacts = array_merge($temp,$ewallet);
    }
}
echo json_encode($contacts);
```

my code generate this format and its wrong:

```
{
    "0":
        {"mobileNumber":"(937) 303-6569"},
    "1":
        {"mobileNumber":"09192522674"},
    "2":
        {
            "mobileNumber":"09373036569"
        },
        "ewallet":["EPIRR9373036569","EPUSD9373036569","EPCHF9373036569","EPIRR9373036569","EPUSD9373036569","EPCHF9373036569"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply array_values to your array.

`json_encode(array_values($$contacts));`

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by this below code:

```
$accountNumbers = "";
$data = UserWallets::where('account_number', 'LIKE', '%' . substr($mobileNumber, 1, strlen($mobileNumber)))->first();
if ($data != null) {

    $contact_ewallets = UserWallets::where('account_number', 'LIKE', '%' . substr($mobileNumber, 1, strlen($mobileNumber)))->get();

    foreach ($contact_ewallets as $value) {
        $accountNumbers[]['accountNumber'] = $value->account_number;
    }

    $epayContacts[] = [
        [
            'mobileNumber' => $obj["mobileNumber"],
            'contactUserId' => $data->user_id,
            'userEwallets' => $accountNumbers
        ]
    ];

}
```